# How can i generate my Apk file with the Mysqlite Database in the project. I dont see the data int the database when i install the APK file

Tags: android

//this is the class that extends the SQliteOpen Helper
//Everything works fine on the emulator just that when i generate the signed //APK i dont see the database file

```
public class HymnDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public final static String dataBaseNames = "HymnDbEwe";
    public final static int VERSION = 1;
    public final static String tableNames = "HymnTable";

    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public HymnDB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "create table "+tableNames+" (HymnNumber INTEGER, HymnSong TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {    
    }   

    public void closeDataBase(){
        if (myDataBase != null){
            myDataBase.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by you don't see the db file? In the emulator, you supposedly have root access so you can view the db file in `/data/data/<application_package_name>/..`. On unroot phone you can't see access path.

Comment: The database file is not shipped with the APK. It is generated when the app is first run and an instance of the database is requested `getReadableDatabase()` for example. The `onCreate()` method will be called for this reason.